Are there any mentions in any research literature of an “implicit speculative epistemic stance”?
I am looking for examples or evidence of what I call the “implicit speculative epistemic stance”.
This resource provides some good ideas regarding how people can have varying epistemic stances regarding their own assertions, focusing on the explicit marker “I think…”. I think that this can happen implicitly, without any verbal artifact. I think this could be called a “speculative” or “conjectural” mood or stance, where someone says something in the form of a declarative sentence, but it’s more like they are sounding aloud a possibility to see whether it is confirmed or refuted by someone in the conversation. For example, if someone saw someone spitting out some raisins they were offered, and said, “You don’t like raisins,” in a particular intonation, it is not a strong epistemic assertion that you don’t like raisins; actually, it is almost “fishing” for confirmation from the person. And the person could respond, “No, I love raisins, I just have painful blisters in my mouth that made me suddenly need to spit out what was in my mouth.”
I am wondering if there is any terminology for this as a speech act.

To me, this sounds like it would fit more with Lacanian psychoanalysis rather than linguistics proper.
